# Rspec test controller with chain methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

How can I test this code in my controller? My problem is with the *wizard_incompleted?* method

```
class ApplicantsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @applicant = current_user.applicant
      @application = @applicant.applications.last


      if @application.wizard_incompleted?
         # some redirect
      end
   end 
end


describe "GET #index" do

   let(:application)    { double('application')}

   it "redirect to wizard if it is incompleted" do
      get :index
      allow_any_instance_of(application).to receive(:wizard_incompleted?).and_return(true)
      expect(response).to redirect_to(new_applicants_application_path)
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can controller test this

```
# app/controllers/applicants_controller.rb
class ApplicantsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @applicant = current_user.applicant
    @application = @applicant.applications.last
    redirect_to "/" if @application.wizard_incompleted?
  end
end
```

Like this

```
# spec/controllers/applicants_controller_spec.rb
require "spec_helper"

describe ApplicantsController, type: :controller do
  it "#index" do
    last_application = double(:last_application, wizard_incompleted?: true)
    applications = double(:applications, last: last_application)
    applicant = double(:applicant, applications: applications)
    current_user = double(:current_user, applicant: applicant)
    expect(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(current_user)
    expect(current_user).to receive(:applicant).and_return(applicant)
    expect(applicant).to receive(:applications).and_return(applications)
    expect(applications).to receive(:last).and_return(last_application)
    expect(last_application).to receive(:wizard_incompleted?).and_return(true)
    get :index
    expect(assigns(:applicant)).to eq applicant
    expect(assigns(:application)).to eq last_application
    expect(response).to redirect_to "/"
  end
end
```

Comment: give or take a couple potential typo's